# Calculating the value of $\frac {1}{D^2+a^2} \sin ax$ where the operator $D = \frac {d}{dx}$. Error in Method $1$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

Calculating the value of $\dfrac {1}{D^2+a^2} \sin ax$ where the operator $D = \dfrac {d}{dx}$

I have tried calculating using two different methods and both of them yield different results. Could someone please pinpoint any error in Method $1$ which I might be making. **My textbook uses method $2$.** Thanks a lot for your help

[[image: **Using Method <span class=]$1$**">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aB0VS.jpg)
[[image: **Using Method <span class=]$2$**">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lV2XI.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These solutions are equivalent. Their difference is a solution of the homogeneous equation, so both are suitable particular solutions. None of them are special in the sense that both value and first derivative at zero are zero.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer